# How do you isolate and compute the corresponding velocity when inputting a specific magnitude of length contraction?

Tags: radicals, special-relativity

How do you isolate the velocity term from within the square root - $lo\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ so that if I'm given the amount that length has been contracted, I can then calculate the corresponding velocity?  For example, if I input a length contraction value of 0.51 the function should output a velocity of .86c

Thank you.

Comment: If l= lo sqrt(1- v^2/c^2) then, squaring both sides, l^2/lo^2= 1- v^2/c^2.  v^2/c^2= 1- l^2/lo/^2.  v^2= c^2(1- l^2/lo^2).  v= csqrt(1- l^2/lo^2).

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}=0.51$

Solve for $v$.

Comment: Regretfully, math isn't my strong suite, especially with radicals.

Comment: Square both sides and then solve.  Otherwise, you need to study more math.

Comment: I was actually able to figure it out - thank you for the push.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it.